# Eclipse projects facets jpa version 2.2 needed

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipse-jee, jpa-2.2

i could not find an answer to my question. I would like to use JPA V2.2 facet. but with the built in Jpa projects facet in eclipse JEE the version is maxed out on V2.1.
Is there any way to update the facet to be 2.2 and not 2.1?

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522302 It has raised a bug and also some patches. Try this if this helps

Comment: How should i get a link so i can update it as a new software? I only find git websites

Comment: Follow this https://dl.bintray.com/danjaredg/eclipse-jpa2.2/eclipse-4.13/